# Usuario con datos que no se marcan en el servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Buenas tardes a todo el auditorio. En mi web applcation tengo un usuario con sus respectivos datos, cuando se hace el registro, espero me comprendan, usuario (en este caso nombre) y contraseña no son los únicos datos, espero haya sido claro.

Bueno, en el servlet a la hora de iniciar sesión con los `request` y `response`, `RequestDispatcher`, `out.println()`, etc, se inicia con nombre contraseña y esos datos a la hora de iniciar sesion, se marcan, se marca el de nombre porque el de contraseña por obviedad tengo que ocultar el dato, el usuario tiene otros datos, el user, correo y puesto.

A esos datos yo los quiero también mandar a llamar con el `setAttribute` o con el `request.getParameter` y en cualquiera siempre me dice que los resultados son `null` y pues me doy cuenta que en eso se debe a que en el método para iniciar sesión no tengo contemplado esos datos y si los llegara a contemplar a fuerza tengo que iniciar sesión con dichos datos porque si no, la sesión no inicia y se produce el error.

¿Tendrá que ver el servlet y tal vez necesite replantear la programación? ¿No conocen un método que deje que esos métodos me dejen de aparecer nulos y me devuelva los datos que quiero? Aquí les dejo los códigos involucrados para que vean lo que está ocurriendo, espero pueda contar con su ayuda y por su atención muchas gracias, que tengan buen fin de semana.

//Es el de las consultas e inicio de sesión

```
public boolean Autenticacion2(String nombre, String contraseña) {
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try { 
            String consulta = "SELECT * FROM rhcontino WHERE nombre = ? AND passw = ?";

            pst = getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            pst.setString(1, nombre);
            pst.setString(2, contraseña);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.absolute(1)) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (getConexion() != null) {
                    getConexion().close();
                }
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        return false;  
    }
```

//Es parte de la codificación del servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String puesto = request.getParameter("puesto");
        String correo = request.getParameter("correo");
        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String empresa = request.getParameter("empresa");
        String contraseña = request.getParameter("passw");
        
        Consultas c = new Consultas();
        
        if(c.Autenticacion2(nombre, contraseña)){
            
            HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(true);
            sesion.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
            sesion.setAttribute("empresa", empresa);
            sesion.setAttribute("nombre", nombre);
            sesion.setAttribute("puesto", puesto);
            sesion.setAttribute("correo", correo);
            
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("FotoContino.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            System.out.println(empresa + ", " + nombre + ", " + correo); 
        }
        else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("errores.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

//Este es para el jsp

```
<%
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
//    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
//    String empresa = request.getParameter("empresa");
    String empresa = (String)sesion.getAttribute("empresa");
    String nombre = (String)sesion.getAttribute("nombre");
    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String contraseña = (String)sesion.getAttribute("passw");
    String puesto = (String)sesion.getAttribute("puesto");
    String correo = (String)sesion.getAttribute("nombre");
    

    if (nombre.equals("")) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Donde les comento que también por medio de jsp los intenté marcar y nada, están nulos los datos

Miren, les dejo por las dudas el método de registrar, por si quieren saber más de lo que está ocurriendo con el código

```
public boolean registrar(String nombre, String usuario, String contraseña, String empresa, String puesto, String correo) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            String consulta = "INSERT INTO rhcontino (nombre, usuario, passw, empresa, puesto, correo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            ps = getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);

            ps.setString(1, nombre);
            ps.setString(2, usuario);
            ps.setString(3, contraseña);
            ps.setString(4, empresa);
            ps.setString(5, puesto);
            ps.setString(6, correo);

            if(ps.executeUpdate()==1){
                return true;
            } 
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Hay una excepción");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(getConexion() != null){
                    getConexion().close();
                }
                if(ps != null){
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Por qué usas `request.getSession(false)`? Si no tienes una sesión creada, te vendría bien que el contenedor web te cree una nueva (enviando el parámetro en true) y así tu `session.getAttribute` tendría de donde tomar datos cuando ya los guardes en sesión...

Comment: PD. El método Autenticación2 no compila, le faltan unas comillas a la consulta SQL inicial. Si arreglas eso, pasa algo diferente?

Comment: ok lo voy a probar, pero no tiene sentido, si no me funcionó en la parte ´.java´ cuando lo probé en la consola con el ´System.out.println();´, donde la sesión se encuentra en ´true´, menos creo que funcione en el .jsp si la sesión se la revierto a true, pero bueno a ver que sale

Comment: PD. Como consejo para la vida, yo a Java no le doy ni espacios ni carácteres especiales en cadenas y variables. Por salud mental, yo usaría variables como `clave` en vez de `contraseña` porque eñe ;)

Comment: Al registrar queda registrado el fulano en la tabla? Ves algún error al correr ese método de Autenticacion2? Hazle debug a esa consulta porque si la sesión no se crea con los datos, el problema seguro está ahí.

Comment: no es una tabla, entras al usuario y te arroja los datos del usuario tipo `select * from latabla where nombre = ? and passw = ?`, en mysql si te avienta todos los datos del usuario, aqui no, en el servlet nadamas te arroja los datos con los que te logueaste que es el nombre en este caso y los demas nada, quedan `null`

Comment: No entendí tu comentario de respuesta, disculpa. Cómo así que no es una tabla si haces `INSERT INTO rhcontino...`, en Autenticacion2 haces `SELECT * FROM rhcontino` y en la validación haces `if(c.Autenticacion2(nombre, contraseña)){`

Comment: no omitas el `where nombre = ? and passw ?;`, por eso no es una tabla, si fuera `select * from tabla` solo, pues si lo fuera, pero no, está especificando los datos del nombre deseado que se va a identificar, los datos del usuario nadamás, no de todos los demás datos

Comment: No estás entendiendo lo que te estoy preguntando. Vamos al chat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132223/discussion-between-alfabravo-and-el-vecino-tlalixcoyan).